# Django forms can't find my template

Tags: django, forms, templates

I'm trying to make use of my first Django form, mostly following [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/).  Do I need to provide an explicit HTML form myself, or does Django's Form class does this for me? If so, how?

Here's my current error:

```
Internal Server Error: /showCrime/query
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/rik/Code/eclipse/djOakData/showCrime/views.py", line 43, in getQuery
    return render(request, 'getQuery.html', {'form': qform})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 53, in render
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 170, in render_to_string
    t = get_template(template_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 146, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 139, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: getQuery.html
```

**`showCrime/views.getQuery():`**

```
def getQuery(request):

    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        qform = simpleQ(request.post)
        if qform.is_valid():
            qryData = qform.cleaned_data

            simpleQ.NQUERY += 1
            qurl = 'showCrime/plots/%s+%s.png' % (qryData['beat'], qryData['crimeCat']) 
            return HttpResponseRedirect(qurl)
    else:
        qform = simpleQ()

    return render(request, 'getQuery.html', {'form': qform})
```

**`showCrime/templates/showCrime/getQuery.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ShowCrime - Query</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>ShowCrime - Query</h1>


    {% if form.errors %}
        <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
        </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="/getQuery/" method="post">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit query">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error suggests that Django can not find the template getQuery.html. Have you properly set TEMPLATE_DIRS variable in your settings.py file? Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/ for setting the same.

Comment: try templates/getQuery.html

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your template loaders are configured in your settings.py;

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

It appears you've placed your template into your app's template directory and namespaced it with the app name. You should include the namespace (your app name) in the call to render.

```
return render(request, 'showCrime/getQuery.html', {'form': qform})
```

Comment: More so the second half of this answer. +1. OP clearly has template inside of a directory `showCrime` -- looking for `getQuery.html` at the root level is the problem.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita, you were right to focus on the `showCrime/` prefix.  but now it's gotten weirder:  despite a line in `showCrime/urls.py` saying `url(r'^query$', views.getQuery, name='getQuery')` i now get a 404 on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/showCrime/query/`  (and the url pattern above is listed as one of the patterns tried part of the debug output?!)

Answer (score -1):

together with @andrewS's hint about the `showCrime/` prefix in the call to `render()`, i was able to fix this by following the suggestion in [Chap7 of the Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html) of using an empty string in the HTML: `<form action="" method="post">`.  there seems some django sensitivity to trailing slashes, etc. that remains beyond me, but this works!