# Django - Custom Form Template cannot find Template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

**Error:**

```
Internal Server Error: /clients/service/edit_equipment/133
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 175, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 161, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name, tried=tried)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: form_as_div.html

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 238, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1064, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 715, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 847, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 914, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 96, in as_div
    return self.render(self.template_name_div)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 75, in render
    return mark_safe(renderer.render(template, context))
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/renderers.py", line 28, in render
    template = self.get_template(template_name)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/renderers.py", line 34, in get_template
    return self.engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 36, in get_template
    reraise(exc, self)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 85, in reraise
    raise new from exc
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: form_as_div.html

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1064, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 715, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 847, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 914, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 96, in as_div
    return self.render(self.template_name_div)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 75, in render
    return mark_safe(renderer.render(template, context))
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/renderers.py", line 29, in render
    return template.render(context, request=request).strip()
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 64, in render
    reraise(exc, self.backend)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 85, in reraise
    raise new from exc
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: form_as_div.html

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 92, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 64, in render
    reraise(exc, self.backend)
  File "/home/wcadev/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 85, in reraise
    raise new from exc
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: form_as_div.html
```

**Code Base**
Specific call: https://github.com/varlenthegray/wcadmin/blob/dev/clients/forms.py#L25-L38

Template Location: https://github.com/varlenthegray/wcadmin/blob/dev/templates/form_as_div.html

I thought it might be related to my settings, however I'm chasing my tail.

I've tried the following URL's as assistance:

[Django forms can't find my template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661305/django-forms-cant-find-my-template)

[django can't find template when trying to use forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699312/django-cant-find-template-when-trying-to-use-forms)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/renderers/#django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#django.template.TemplateDoesNotExist

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Django, in the current configuration, isn't even looking in the main Templates directory. I've moved it to an app directory and it's working. This solves my challenge.